# Automatic update of cells on a second tab when they are merely a copy of the previous tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, database-administration

I have 2 tabs in excel, part of the information on tab one is to be copied into tab 2. It works ok until I insert a new row into the tab 1 spreadsheet. That change to the cells does not reflect in the second tab. what am I missing??

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to group the sheets (tabs). While you are in one sheet, hold down the Ctrl key and click on the tab for the other sheet. You will see that both tabs are now white. When the 2 sheets are grouped like this any change you make on one will affect the other, so you can insert the row on one sheet and Excel will insert it in the other.

When you want to edit the sheets individually click on one of the tabs-you will see the other tab has become gray again so any changes you now make will only affect one sheet.

Comment: **CTRL**-click to ungroup?